# Delegate does not contain a definition for CreateDelegate in .net core

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-core

I'm trying to use delegates for reflection in dotNet core web application. Below is the sample of the code.

```
Action action = (Action) Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action), method)
```

Compiler gives the following error:

```
'Delegate' does not contain a definition for 'CreateDelegate'   ConsoleApp2..NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0'
```

Is there any work around for creating delegates in .net Core?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `MethodInfo.CreateDelegate` instead.

```
MethodInfo methodInfo = target.GetType().GetMethod(nameof(FooMethod));

Action action = (Action) methodInfo.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action), target);
```

`Delegate.CreateDelegate` is expected to return in .NET Core 2.0: [.NET API Catalog](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Delegate.CreateDelegate(Type,MethodInfo))